# javascript change date format to Chile character in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I want to change date "2019-10-07" to  "7 de Octubre de 2019" in nodejs.
Is it possible to change it?

```
"2019-10-07"  => "7 de Octubre de 2019" (nodeJS or pure javascript)
```

Comment: Consider reading about internationalisation for node https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html? The `Intl` object may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Comment: Thanks, You saved my time. I just found an answer, I will try to do it. :)

Comment: You can also use the language and options for the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), e.g. `new Date("2019-10-07").toLocaleString('es',{day:'numeric',month:'long',year:'numeric'});` gives "7 de octubre de 2019".

Comment: It is a good way without a library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use https://momentjs.com/ for it.

```
var localLocale = moment();
moment.locale('es'); // change the global locale to Spanish
localLocale.format('LLLL');
moment().format('LLLL'); // Domingo 21 Marzo 2021 11:01
```

About the format,

Comment: An answer should not require a library not tagged or mentioned in the OP. You might suggest a library in a comment.